# How to create a forecasting model that takes working days per month in consideration?

Tags: r, events, forecasting

I would like to create a forecasting model that is sensitive to the number of working days in a month. For example, this year (2012) Christmas is in the middle of a week and therefore the month of December is significantly shorter than when Christmas is during a weekend. I know that commercial packages like ForecastPro have the ability to do this with the assistance of what they call "helper files". I was wondering whether somebody is able to demonstrate this in R?

I have the following time series, which I would like to forecast beyond the last period.

```
ts <- structure(c(88.3, 97.1, 110.2, 93.1, 104.7, 102.6, 94.8, 85.6, 
103.8, 109.6, 111.4, 98.6, 102.5, 101.8, 113.6, 99, 104.6, 106, 
99.2, 87.5, 101.6, 111.3, 106.9, 91.6, 99.4, 100.3, 108.3, 106.2, 
104.1, 105.2, 103.9, 85.8, 107.5, 113.7, 110, 97, 101.6, 102.4, 
112, 104.1, 103.3, 104.4, 106.1, 83.9, 112.2, 117.7, 110.2, 104.7, 
101.8, 106.9, 123.3, 112.5, 108.7, 117.4, 109.3, 92.3, 118, 117.6, 
121.3, 108, 106.5, 109.6, 121, 116.3, 114, 121.8, 109.9, 99.1, 
124, 121.2, 128.2, 113.1, 117.5, 119.4, 139.9, 119.4, 131, 131.3, 
117.1, 107.1, 128.7, 133.7, 134.6, 115.3, 126.3, 124.9, 140.5, 
123.6, 129.9, 132.9, 127.6, 113.1, 130, 141.5, 139.4, 112.8, 
132.5, 133.8, 132.7, 138.7, 128.5, 133.2, 130.8, 105.5, 134.4, 
134.4, 118.3, 99.9, 102.8, 103.3, 113.8, 104.6, 101.4, 109.9, 
109.9, 90.6, 118.1, 119.8, 115.8, 104.2, 104.3, 109.5, 128.7, 
116.2, 115.2, 126.2, 116.9, 102.6, 127, 126.6, 129, 115.3, 115.8, 
118.4, 137.3, 119.4, 128.1, 125.7, 117.1, 109.4, 130.3, 123.7, 
127.9, 111.3, 117.1, 120.5, 132, 115.5, 123.3, 122.9, 118.3), .Tsp = c(2000, 
2012.5, 12), class = "ts")
```

I also have the following information about the working days (haven't mapped all holidays yet), but that shouldn't limit us in looking at the concept.

```
workingdays <- structure(c(21L, 21L, 23L, 20L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 22L, 
22L, 21L, 23L, 20L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 20L, 23L, 22L, 
21L, 23L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 20L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 20L, 23L, 22L, 
20L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 21L, 20L, 
23L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 20L, 23L, 
20L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 20L, 22L, 21L, 
23L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 20L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 
21L, 23L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 20L, 23L, 22L, 20L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 20L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 21L, 20L, 23L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 
22L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 20L, 
23L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 20L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 
21L, 22L), .Tsp = c(2000, 2013.91666666667, 12), class = "ts")
```

You will notice that the number months of which the working days are included extends significantly beyond the scope of the first time series (ts).

Appreciate if there is somebody who can point me in the right direction (e.g. what functions to use) to create a forecasting model that allows me to forecast the ts-series while taking the workingdays-series in consideration. In the forecast this will mean that it will adjust the value on the basis of the number of workingdays in the month of the forecast. I am a bit stuck and don't seem to be able to imagine how to do this with any of the forecasting/timeseries functions that I know of.

Thanks for your help! 
Jochem

Comment: What have you already tried (apart from loading your timeseries into a `ts` object. What packages have you tried (e.g. forecast, zoo), and why did you not succeed  in getting what you want from them? Right now your question is a bit too broad imo, StackOverflow is for specific programming questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Paul. You might be right that my question is broad or actually, I might be asking two questions at once that I need to put in separate questions. However, fact of the matter is that I am a bit stuck and that reviewing (and googling) hasn't led to a insight into the right direction.

Comment: Your first problem is that your data are in an awkward format for modeling. You probably want to reshape (possibly with reshape2 package) that time series so that there is a single column that identifies the month and a single column with the value.  To work with times, I recommend lubridate package.  And to easily identify holidays, I recommend TimeWarp and Holidays packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
require(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(ts,xreg=window(workingdays,end=2012.5))
fcast <- forecast(fit,xreg=window(workingdays,start=2012.51))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at the [CRAN Timeseries Taskview](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) for packages that are relevant for your problem. If you have any specfic issues with a specific function/package, you can ask a new question here.